# n-1 subset products

Tags: combinatorics

Write each element of [n-1] on a separate card, then randomly select a number of cards and take the product. Then do this for all 2^(n-1) subsets (the empty product is 1). What is the sum of these 2^(n-1) products?

I am looking for a combinatorial explanation of this however.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you can get the sum you're looking for via the product
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(1+i).
$$

Comment: My immediate thought is to relate this to the number of ways of placing parenthesis around the [n-1] elements and multiplying those that are in the parenthesis and add all of said products. This would relate the question to permutations and the signless sterling numbers of the first kind. I have a sneaking suspicion that the answer is n! but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the general product
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n(1+a_i).
$$
This product looks like
$$
1^n+1^{n-1}\sum_ia_i+1^{n-2}\sum_{i\neq j}a_ia_j+\ldots+a_1a_2\cdots a_n.
$$
This is grouped by the powers of $1$. This is also equal to the sum of the products of any subsets of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, letting the empty product equal $1$. Therefore if your set is $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, then the sum of the products of any subset is, as you said, $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_i)=n!$.

Comment: So it makes sense to me that this is correct, but I am looking for guidance on how to solve this problem combinatorially. I found this problem in a chapter on permutations and their applications to combinatorics so I figure they will be of some use in some way.

Comment: I'm not sure of a better way to do it.